# Begin drag and drop after long tap

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, uigesturerecognizer

I'm creating a view where its subviews can be re-arranged with drag and drop, after activating the "edition mode" via a long tap.

I use for that two gesture reconizer a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` and a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`.

Everything works great, but i wanna be able to start dragging my subviews without having to tap again on my view (like when you re-arrange your icon on the springboard).

Is there any way to do such a thing ?

EDIT :

I've tried :

```
func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    var res = false

    if ((gestureRecognizer == longTapGesture && otherGestureRecognizer == panGesture) || (gestureRecognizer == panGesture && otherGestureRecognizer == panGesture)) {
        res = true
        println("")
    }
    return true
}
```

without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all those 2 gesture recognizers should work nicely together. Normally one of them would cancel the other one. To prevent that you can use UIGestureRecognizerDelegate method  [gestureRecognizer: shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:) and return YES for both recognizers.

After that you need to have a boolean property to lock your pan effect before long press occurs. UILongPressGestureRecognizer target method should only perform something if this property is set to YES. Remember to set this property to NO, when pan gesture finishes/resets.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but it's not working i'm editing my post to put a sample of code.

Comment: Also i'm adding the pan gesture to the view when I detect the long tap event if that matter

Comment: That matters. Add pan gesture when view is presented. It should always be enabled, and you decide to animate your view based on your boolean property.

Comment: Not sure to get you, my pan gesture is created with the proper target, i'm only calling the addGestureReconizer and the remove at the appropriate time

Comment: Probably that's why it doesn't work, because the time you added pan gesture, touch is already began. Normally touch begin starts a gesture recognizer. Have your pan gesture always functional. But start doing your pan animations **after** user long presses. To know if user long pressed or not, you need an additional boolean property i say.